# How to make pip3 install a command which could then be typed in the console from anywhere?

Tags: python, linux, pip, package

I want to install `pyocd` package:

```
pip3 install pyocd
```

the installation procedure gives me a warning:

```
WARNING: The script pylink is installed in '/home/mercury0014/.local/bin' which is not on PATH
```

and thus typing `pyocd list` into the terminal returns an error:

pyocd: command not found

The problem here is that on my machine the console does not search the directory `/home/mercury0114/.local/bin` to find the command `pyocd`

Can I call `pip3 install ...` command in a way that the command `pyocd ...` would work **immediately** after installation?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip3 install pyocd --install-option="--install-scripts=/usr/local/bin" --upgrade
```

The package will be installed to `~/mercury0114/.local` directory but `/usr/local/bin` directory will contain a symbolic link to the `pyocd` binary. Since `/usr/local` is in the PATH you can now call `pyocd` in the terminal.

Comment: @TinNguyen The solution to add `/home/mercury0114/.local/bin` to `PATH` is exactly what I do not want (for different users `mercury0114` will be replaced by another name and thus not work). -t specifies a directory where you want to install the package and passing `/usr/local/` as an argument will guarantee that when `pyocd` command is installed to `/usr/local/bin`, you will be able to use it by typing `pyocd` from the shell

Comment: Removed comments, since answer has been adjusted; quick edit: it is often ill-advised to pip install with sudo since it can bring in other kind of problems. Pip install is then executed as root instead of the user but if a user has insufficient rights the package may not work even though it is installed.

Answer (score -1):

You could use: pip install "package" -t "directory"

Comment: Your answer is misleading. You are specifying a `PYTHONPATH`. A place where Python packages are installed. He's asking about `PATH-System variables`. The solution is to add the folder path `/home/mercury0014/.local/bin` your `PATH` or to specify a different folder path but you can't do this via the `PYTHONPATH`. I don't know how to modify that so I can't provide an answer.
Also his error doesn't come from installing `pyocd` his `pylink` was installed faulty in the first place. It is a consecutive error.

Answer (score -3):

You need to have pip installed in the environment. You could uninstall and reinstall python. if you do that you have to make sure you are adding python to the path and you are installing pip.